# Create Windows-compatable symbolic links in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, 64-bit, symbolic-link

I am using a SSD which is running out of space. Like 300 kB remaining. I need a symbolic link from the Program Files folders(32 bit and 64 bit) on the C drive to the E drive. Unfortunatly, the mklink command only lets you make symbolic links if the folder already doesn't exist. I duplicated these folders on the E drive but can't modify the Program Files folders while the system is running because some of those programs need to be on full time(like Windows Programs). Any way to make a symbolic link in Ubuntu that Windows will recognize?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this too. The way I got around it was creating a symbolic link named `Program Files2` through Windows. Switching to Ubuntu, you can delete the `Program Files` folder and rename the link, removing the `2`. This should work for any type of link. Before attempting this, make sure you have a back up, or some way to revert to the old set up. With the copy on the E drive, this isn't too problematic; you'd just have to copy it back over. I've had a couple programs (I can't remember which) throw errors when operating on symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just ended up buying a new SSD and duplicating using DriveXML.

Comment: That's generally a more stable solution. Glad you got things to work for you.